# "Легко()воспаменяемый": слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография

Надо было написать один текст о горючих веществах, и там встречалось слово "легко()воспламеняемый". Ворд подчеркивает как ошибку и предлагает раздельное написание. А вообще, можно написать слитно: "легковоспламеняемое вещество"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сочетание наречия с прилагательным или причастием, ставшее термином, пишется слитно: тяжелораненый, вечнозеленые, легковоспламеняемый...